# Create a list where the first parameter is the file name and the second parameter is the first line of the file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I want to create a list where the first parameter is the file name and the second parameter is the first line of that file. i have already extracted the file names and first lines into two separate lists :

```py
import os

path = 'E:\Python Stuff\logtest\logs'

files = []
firstlines = []
# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if '.log' in file:
            files.append(os.path.join(r, file))

for f in files:
    with open(f) as fl:
        line = fl.readline().partition(".")
        firstlines.append(line[0])
```

How can I merge both of together?
I want it like `list = [filename : firstline],[filename : firstline],..`

Comment: That's not a list, that's a dictionary

Comment: Read file when `append` into `files`

Comment: How can i merge both the lists together. I would like to use filename as key and firstline as data

Comment: Read up on [Tutorial - 5.5. Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
my_list = []
for i in range(len(files)):
    my_list.append([files[i],firstlines[i]])
```

if you want to use the key-value structure, then you have to use [Python's dictionaries](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp). It could look like this:

```
my_dict = {}
for i in range(len(files)):
    my_list[files[i]] = firstlines[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

checkout this sweet one-liner, since you already created the two list

```
dict(zip(first_list, second_list))
```

it creates a dictionary based on the two lists, zipped together. This should work directly in your code

```
merged_dict = dict(zip(files, firstlines))
```

it will look like this: {"filename1": "firstline1", "filename2": "firstline2", ETC...}

you can work with this merged_dict like so:

```
for key, value in merged_dict.items():
    print(key, value)
```